# Freeing non-malloc'd memory

Tags: c, visual-studio, malloc, free

Let's say I declare the following array:

```
char *arr[3];
```

During running the program, depending on the user's inputs, I may or may not allocate strings of memory into this array (meaning `arr[i]`).

Is it safe to `free(arr[i])` at the end of the program without checking which of them I allocated? Or could this cause errors?

Thanks!

Comment: It's safe if `arr[i]` points to `NULL`, calling `free` with an uninitialized pointer is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Calling free on `char *arr[3];` is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  On some platforms, it could cause a segmentation violation.  On *all* platforms - it's just "wrong".  Don't do it!  See also:  [free() function without malloc or calloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110767/free-function-without-malloc-or-calloc)

Comment: @paulsm4: if `char *arr[3];` is defined as a global variable, it will be initialized to null pointers and calling `free(arr[0])` will be fine. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to pass a null pointer to `free`, so if your array is initialized with null pointers, you can safely free all `arr[i]`, assuming you only store pointers return by `malloc()` and friends and do not free them elsewhere.

Define the array as

```
char *arr[3] = { NULL, NULL, NULL };
```

or simply

```
char *arr[3] = { 0 };
```

`NULL`, `0` and `'\0'` may be used to specify a null pointer, but it is advisable to follow a simple rule of clarity:

- use `NULL` for a null pointer,
- use `0` for a null integer,
- use `'\0'` for a null byte in an array of `char`, which is also called the null terminator.

And you can use `= { 0 };` as an initializer for any C object: all elements and members will be intialized to the zero value of their type, except for unions where only the first member is initialized this way.

Comment: One question, can we put `\0` instead of `NULL`?

Comment: @RohanBari: If you mean `'\0'`, technically yes, because `'\0'` is an `int` constant with the value `0`, therefore it is a null pointer in a pointer context. But it would be **very confusing** to use a character constant to initialize a pointer. `char *arr[3]` is an array of 3 pointers, not a pointer to an array of 3 `char`, which is written `char (*arr)[3]`. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296843/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-0

Comment: Mhmm... It's clearer to me now. Thanks! I'll take a deeper look at their differences. +1

Comment: Here is a simple rule of clarity: use `NULL` for a null pointer, `0` for a null integer, `'\0'` for a null byte in an array of `char`, which is also called the null terminator.

Comment: @chqrlie: I'd add another rule: Use `{0}` to zero-initialize all members of a (possibly nested) array or structure, regardless of types, in cases where no other values would make sense [e.g. if one has a structure that contains the number of valid items in an array, followed by the array, I'd regard the use of ...`0, {0}`... to initialize the count to zero and all items to zero cleaner than the explicit listing of values for all the elements.

Comment: Just because you "can", doesn't mean you "should".  At best, deliberately calling "free()" on an object you know you didn't malloc() is "perverse".  It's also unnecessary code/unnecessary runtime overhead/unneeded code bloat.  At worst - it's a maintenance nightmare - and a potential bug waiting to happen as the code is modified.  DON'T DO IT!

Comment: @FoggyDay: calling `free` on a pointer you know is either `NULL` or an allocated block is fine and well defined. Testing for null in this case is just redundant.

Answer (score 0):

The only safe values to pass to `free` are null pointers and values returned by `malloc`, and to be clear on that, those values returned by `malloc` shall only be `free`d **once** until next time they're returned by `malloc` (or `calloc`, or `realloc`).